# insert with subquery and select

Tags: sql, select, insert, subquery

I would like to insert rows into a table using  a select statement to query specific data but use data from a different table as part of the insert.  EXmaple:
Table A: Clients  where data is being queried and copied
Table B: MailOptOut where data is being inserted

I want to insert in MailOptOut table two values, a hardcoded field 'Summer Promotion' and then the acct# from the clients table (client.acct_no)

Here is my code that isn't working:

```
INSERT INTO PL00.DBO.mailcoptout (MC_NAME, ACCT_NO)
VALUES 
('Summer Service Promo',  client.acct_no),
('Referral Rewards Doubled', client.acct_no),
('Holiday Decorating 1',  client.acct_no),
('Holiday Decorating 2', client.acct_no)
select client.acct_no, mailcoptout.* from plshared.dbo.client  left join PL00.DBO.mailcoptout on mailcoptout.ACCT_NO = client.ACCT_NO
where client.U_SOLICIT = 'y'
and client.acct_no = '131335'
and client.INACTIVE <> 'y'
and mailcoptout.MC_NAME is null
```

Comment: Please include the error (if any) and explain what isn't working.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Your `insert` statement has two columns being inserted and who know how many you are attempting.  Please edit your question and provide sample data.  Also, tag the question with the database yiou are using.

Comment: using sql server management studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
INSERT INTO PL00.DBO.mailcoptout (MC_NAME, ACCT_NO)
    select x.mc_name, client.acct_no
    from plshared.dbo.client c left join
         PL00.DBO.mailcoptout mc
         on mailcoptout.ACCT_NO = client.ACCT_NO cross join
         (select 'Summer Service Promo' as MC_NAME union all,
          select 'Referral Rewards Doubled' as MC_NAME union all
          select 'Holiday Decorating 1' as MC_NAME union all
          select 'Holiday Decorating 2' as MC_NAME
         ) x
    where c.U_SOLICIT = 'y' and
          c.acct_no = '131335' and
          c.INACTIVE <> 'y' and
          mc.MC_NAME is null;
```

Comment: i tried this and got this error: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "mailcoptout.ACCT_NO" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "client.ACCT_NO" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "client.acct_no" could not be bound.

Comment: tweak a few errors: INSERT INTO PL00.DBO.mailcoptout (MC_NAME, ACCT_NO)
    select x.mc_name, c.acct_no
    from plshared.dbo.client c left join
         PL00.DBO.mailcoptout mc
         on mc.ACCT_NO = c.ACCT_NO cross join
         (select 'Summer Service Promo' as MC_NAME union all
          select 'Referral Rewards Doubled' as MC_NAME union all
          select 'Holiday Decorating 1' as MC_NAME union all
          select 'Holiday Decorating 2' as MC_NAME
         ) x
    where c.U_SOLICIT = 'y' and
          c.INACTIVE <> 'y' and
          mc.MC_NAME is null;